# How to find remaining addresses in DHCP pool?

Tags: dhcp

I have an ubuntu machine hooked to a wall ethernet socket.  That socket is connected to a whatsit somewhere that is running a DHCP server, which issues my machine an IP address.  I would like to find out, from my ubuntu machine, which addresses in the DHCP pool from which my machine was given an address are available and which are assigned.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Nope.  You'd need to look at whatever is tracking the leases on teh actual DHCP server device itself.  Note that how to do that will depend on which DHCPD you are running....

Comment: I cannot do that thing.  It is worth noting that I can see at least *one* address in the DHCP pool which is unassigned by simply requesting an IP address.  Can this process somehow be exploited to obtain information about multiple available IP addresses?

Answer (score 3):

DHCP would not provide the information necessary to get you this information.  It has a pool of addresses and says, "I see you want an IP address.  Here, use this one."

If you wanted, you *could* release your IP address and request another one but if the DHCP server is smart, it will just re-assign you the same IP address.

From an attack perspective, if you want to see which IP addresses you can use, you can always ping all the IP addresses in your subnet, see which which ones respond, assuming that the hosts allow ping backs.

Comment: Do I need to release my current IP to request another one?  Could I send a DHCP request with a different MAC and get a different IP address?

Comment: yes scott shortly said,but if you not aware about dhcp Protokoll i please you to read at least Wikipedia about it. its like a ping pong game; ping ( hello i am MAC-Address, need an IP) ; pong ( Good Day MAC-Address your ip is.....)

Comment: I'm going to assume positive intent here and assume you are white-hat hacking.  Yes, without going into the details of how DHCP works, if you have another MAC address, you would be able to get a new DHCP address.  You could then cycle through MAC addresses, until you either A) Max out the server's pool of IPs; B) You get all of the valid IP addresses; C) the network administrator shuts you down.  Since you are wired in, any competent sysadmin would see a large spike of DHCP requests coming from the port and turn it off.